# Python 2.7 contradicting python3

Tags: apt, python, python3

I have both python 2.7 and python 3.7 installed on my system. the issue here is python2 still overrides python3.i mean when trying to install new packages, it still displays the DEPRECATION message. please how do i make python3 my main python version and use it?

if i try 'sudo-apt-update' it always throws back this error message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Please how can i solve all these? i believe its the python2 causing the problem. i am considering   to uninstall it. which way forward?

Comment: In /usr/bin, try unlinking python and then relinking python3 to python.

Comment: please how can i do that? i am in the /usr/bin directory i dont know which file to edit.

Comment: You haven't said what OS/release you are using, but currently supported releases of Ubuntu should have `python2` and `python3` installed & working. For most releases, `python` should default to `python2` but as you haven't given your release, we cannot be specific (`python3 -V` reports 3.8.2 for my release, but your release likely should report a 2 release)

Comment: I am using `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS`. `python3 -V` reports `python 3.7.5` on the terminal. The issue is, `python2` still runs as default. using the command `python --version` it displays `Python 2.7.16 :: Anaconda, Inc.`

Comment: Solved in 20.04 - the `python` command has been removed completely. Use `python2` or `python3` appropriately.

Comment: @user535733 how do you mean?

Comment: @UniqueEzra you are essentially asking "*How do I make the `python` command use Py3 instead of Py2?*" DON'T DO IT - On 18.04, that will cause breakage. Use the command `python3` to refer to Py3.